# Find duplicate phrases (not just words) in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Let's say I have an array:

```
[
"I want **a dog**",
"**A dog** is here",
"Pet **a dog**",
"A **red cat**",
"**red cat** is cute"
...
]
```

How do I figure out what the duplicate *phrases* are, not just words?
For example, I'd like "**a dog**" and "**red cat**" to be returned.

Most existing posts I found are only about getting individual words, not phrases (multiple words).

Comment: have you tried anything?at least a logical approach ?

Comment: how big your array is.

Comment: There are asterisks in your array?

Comment: Well the easiest to understand approach would presumably be to iterate over the array, and for each item work out all of its possible multi-word phrases, then for each of those phrases iterate over all of the other array items doing a case-insensitive search for the current phrase, adding matches to an output array (also keeping match count or other metadata as desired).

Comment: I don't know the solution with the best time complexity, but one thing you could do is _first_ look for duplicate words, and then look _around_ each duplicate word to see if there's a duplicate phrase.  Every duplicate phrase consists of one (or two) or more sequential duplicate words.

Comment: Do you actually need *all* duplicate phrases or just the largest of each group? Suppose you had the sentences "Tom has a dog" and "Bill knows that Tom has a dog". This would give us duplicates of "Tom has", "Tom has a", "Tom has a dog", "has a", "has a dog", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving us too little information. I'm assuming you're splitting by spaces. ES6 to the rescue :). Sets have O(1) lookup for when you're looking for repeated phrases.

edit: Just realized that you can cut down space complexity by a ton with some small modifications. If you want me to do that, give me a shoutout.

```
const buildAllPhrases = sentence => {
    const splitSentence = sentence.split(" ")
    const phraseSize = splitSentence.length
    const allPhrases = []
    for (let i = phraseSize; i > 0; i--) {
        for (let y = 0; y + i <= phraseSize; y++) {
            allPhrases.push(splitSentence.slice(y, y + i))
        }
    }
    return allPhrases.map(phrase => phrase.join(" "))
}

const findRepeats = sentences => {
    const allPhrases = new Set()
    const repeatedPhrases = new Set()
    let phrases
    sentences.forEach(phrase => {
        phrases = buildAllPhrases(phrase)
        phrases.forEach(subPhrase => {
            if (allPhrases.has(subPhrase)) {
                repeatedPhrases.add(subPhrase)
            } else {
                allPhrases.add(subPhrase)
            }
        })
    })
    return [...repeatedPhrases]
}

const sample = [
"I want **a dog**",
"**A dog** is here",
"Pet **a dog**",
"A **red cat**",
"**red cat** is cute"
]

findRepeats(sample)
//['dog**', '**a dog**', '**a', '**red cat**', '**red', 'cat**', 'is']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not final version of the javascript function, and it can be optimized further. Few changes may also be required, but it can be starter for your requirement.

```js
function GetPhrases(stringsArray) {
    //Array to split your string into words.
    var jaggedArray = [];

    //Array to keep indexes of strings where 2 matching words are found together.
    var newArray = [];

    var phrases = [];

    //Loop through your array
    for (var ic = 0; ic < stringsArray.length; ic++) {
        //Convert every item to array of strings
        var items = (stringsArray[ic]).split(" ");
        for (var it = 0; it < items.length; it++)
            items[it] = items[it].toLowerCase();

        //Push the array of words to main array  
        jaggedArray.push(items);
    }
    //console.log(jaggedArray);

    // Loop through the main array
    for (var iLoop = 0; iLoop < jaggedArray.length; iLoop++) {
        // For every item in main array, loop through words in that item.
        for (var ik = 0; ik < jaggedArray[iLoop].length; ik++) {
            var currentWord = jaggedArray[iLoop][ik];
            // For every word, check its existence in the main array in all items coming after current item.
            for (var il = iLoop + 1; il < jaggedArray.length; il++) {
                // Find the index in the string.
                var indexOfFind = jaggedArray[il].indexOf(currentWord);


                if (indexOfFind > 0) {
                    // if matching index is more than 0, find if the word before this word also matches. 
                    var indexofPrevWord = jaggedArray[il].indexOf(jaggedArray[iLoop][ik - 1]);
                    if ((indexofPrevWord >= 0) && (indexofPrevWord == (indexOfFind - 1)))
                        if (newArray.indexOf(il + " - " + iLoop) < 0)
                            newArray.push(il + " - " + iLoop);

                    // if matching index is more than 0, find if the word after this word also matches. 
                    var indexofNextWord = jaggedArray[il].indexOf(jaggedArray[iLoop][ik + 1]);
                    if (indexofNextWord >= 0 && (indexofNextWord == (indexOfFind + 1)))
                        if (newArray.indexOf(il + " - " + iLoop) < 0)
                            newArray.push(il + " - " + iLoop);
                }
                else if (indexOfFind = 0) {
                    // if matching index is more than 0, find if the word after this word also matches. 
                    var indexofNewWord = jaggedArray[il].indexOf(jaggedArray[iLoop][ik + 1]);
                    if (indexofNewWord >= 0 && (indexofNewWord == (indexOfFind + 1)))
                        if (newArray.indexOf(il + " - " + iLoop) < 0)
                            newArray.push(il + " - " + iLoop);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    //newArray will store indexes of those string arrays in jagged array which has a matching sequence of atleast 2 words.
    //console.log(newArray);
    //Loop through newArray
    for (var itl = 0; itl < newArray.length; itl++) {
        var item = newArray[itl];
        var values = item.split(" - ");

        var firstArrayItem = jaggedArray[values[0]];
        var secondArrayItem = jaggedArray[values[1]];
        var phraseStartPoint = [];

        //for every word in firstItem
        for (var iy = 0; iy < firstArrayItem.length - 1; iy++) {

            var t = iy + 1;
            // check if that word and next word exist in second array
            if (secondArrayItem.toString().indexOf(firstArrayItem[iy] + "," + firstArrayItem[t]) >= 0) {
                // if they do exist, get the indexes of these and store in local array, if they are not there, since we do not want repeating words later. 
                if (phraseStartPoint.indexOf(iy) < 0)
                    phraseStartPoint.push(iy);
                if (phraseStartPoint.indexOf(t) < 0)
                    phraseStartPoint.push(t);
            }
        }

        var str = "";
        // Prepare the phrase from the local array and push into phrases array, if it not exists there.
        for (var ifinalLoop = 0; ifinalLoop < phraseStartPoint.length; ifinalLoop++) {
            str = str + firstArrayItem[phraseStartPoint[ifinalLoop]] + " ";
        }

        if (phrases.indexOf(str) < 0)
            phrases.push(str);

    }
    return phrases;
}

var stringsArray = [
"I want a dog",
"A dog is here",
"Pet a dog is cute",
"A red cat is here",
"red cat is cute"
];

var result = GetPhrases(stringsArray);
// Print the phrases array.
for (var iPhrase = 0; iPhrase < result.length; iPhrase++) {
    console.log(result[iPhrase]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with regex you can detect duplicates in strings.
According to this regex: 
[`(?:.*?)(\b\w.{3,}\b)(?:.*?)(\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/QT1dD9/4/) ,

it only works if you're looking for twice the same pattern.
note: you can replace `3` in `{3,}` by any other integer and see the changes.
This paramater contrains the minimal string lenght you're looking for twice.